# MongoDB $and query on multiple fields and values within a single embedded document

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm looking for a way to query a collection like this:

```
[{ 
  name: "Parent 1",
  items: [
    { name: "Child 1", age: "60" },
    { name: "Child at heart", age: "27" }
  ]
 },

 {
  name: "Parent 2",
  items: [
    { name: "Child 3", age: "10" },
    { name: "Child 4", age: "15" },
    { name: "Child at heart", age: "60" }
  ]
 }
]
```

With a query like this:

```
db.collection.find( 'items.name' => "Child at heart", 'items.age' => "60" )
```

And get a result of just the object with name "Parent 2". That is, I want to query the documents looking for the ones that contain an embedded item that has **both** a name of "Child at heart", **and** an age of "60" in the **same** embedded document. Instead this query returns both documents, "Parent 1" and "Parent 2".

How do I query with an $and condition on different fields within the same embedded document?

Thanks.

Comment: use $elemMatch : http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem here is that `$and` takes each condition, applies it to all embedded documents, and counts the document as meeting the condition if any embedded document is a match. It doesn't correlate the conditions.

The operator you want is `$elemMatch`. It performs the correlation you're looking for. Here's the right query:

```
db.collection.find({items: {$elemMatch: {name: 'Child at heart', age: '60'} }})
```

`items` is the name of the array you want to search.

The output of the query on your sample data:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("51a012f0ac3dfe4f0c05ca89"),
"name" : "Parent 2",
"items" : [
    {
        "name" : "Child 3",
        "age" : "10"
    },
    {
        "name" : "Child 4",
        "age" : "15"
    },
    {
        "name" : "Child at heart",
        "age" : "60"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response Paul. I have accepted this as the answer.